# How to print a page from electron (with vue) with the same result in windows and mac

Tags: css, windows, printing, electron

I'm having print stylesheets for a page in vue.js When calling `window.print();` on windows the page gets smaller printed as it should be (see Image). When I do the same on Mac it prints it perfectly. Also the preview on Mac is correct but on Windows it isn't.

[Windows example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwAT4.jpg)

There is a sidebar in the application which had a transition. I added the following for the whole application:

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 210mm 297mm;
    margin: 15mm;
  }

  * {
    transition: none !important;
  }
}
```

The sidebar has a `display: none;` when getting printed. As well as the footer because it is not needed on paper.
Also the container of the site has special styles to keep the full size

```
@media print {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0 !important;
  max-width: initial;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

I didn't want to automatically create a pdf so far because I only have one browser (chrome) which should handle the print styles. It would make it selectable and nicer in case of resolution (I think).

I expect to have the same print result from electron with vue on Windows and Mac. Actually I only need it to be correct on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the specific size setting the page prints at the moment correct. So I removed these lines:

```css
@page {
  size: 210mm 297mm;
  margin: 15mm;
}
```